# Bootstrap dropdown with input

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i'm trying to create bootstrap dropdown with a dynamic input, but the problem is i cant manage to type in it properly .
here is an example:
http://www.bootply.com/126312

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#addToFavorites').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="כתוב שם ולחץ אנטר להוספה">');
    $('.form-control').focus(); // this is added
});
```